# Trying to optimize a query that picks an 'approximate closest record'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table that contains a lot of data, where we particularly care about the `date` field.  The reason for this is that the data volume just went up ~30x, and the old ways will fall apart soon. The query I hope you can help me optimize needs to:

- take a list of dates (generated by a cte based table-valued function)
- retrieve a single record for each of those dates

  - based on some definition of 'nearest'

For instance, the current table contains data in 5 second (+/- a little) intervals.  I need to sample that table and get the record that falls closest to a 30 second interval.

What I have right now works just fine.  I'm simply curious if there is a way to optimize it more.  If I can do it in Linq To SQL, that would be neat too.  I am even interested in suggestions on indexes, given the amount of date values (~2 million rows min).

```
declare @st  datetime ; set @st  = '2012-01-31 05:05:00';
declare @end datetime ; set @end = '2012-01-31 05:10:00';

select distinct
    log.*   -- id, 
from 
    dbo.fn_GenerateDateSteps(@st, @end, 30) as d
        inner join lotsOfLogData log on l.Id = (
            select top 1 e.[Id]
            from 
                lotsOfLogData as log  -- contains data in 5 second intervals
            where
                log.stationId = 1000 
                -- search for dates in a certain range
                AND utcTime between DateAdd(s, -10, dt) AND DateAdd(s, 5, dt)
            order by
                -- get the 'closest'. this can change a little, but will always 
                -- be based on a difference between the date
                abs(datediff(s, dt, UtcTime)) 
        )
    -- updated the query to be correct. stadionId should be inside the subquery
```

The table structure of lotsOfLogData is below.  There are relatively few station IDs (maybe 50), but lots of records for each.  We know the station id when we query.

```
create table ##lotsOfLogData (
    Id          bigint      identity(1,1) not null
,   StationId   int         not null
,   UtcTime     datetime    not null
    -- 20 other fields, used for other calculations
)
```

**fn_GenerateDateSteps** returns a dataset like this, for the parameters given:

```
[DT]
2012-01-31 05:05:00.000
2012-01-31 05:05:30.000
2012-01-31 05:06:00.000
2012-01-31 05:06:30.000  (and so on, every 30 seconds)
```

I have done this with a temporary table as well, in this manner, but that came out just a little bit more expensive.

```
declare @dates table ( dt datetime, ClosestId bigint); 
insert into @dates (dt) select dt from dbo.fn_GenerateDateSteps(@st, @end, 30)
update @dates set closestId = ( -- same subquery as above )
select * from lotsOfLogData inner join @dates on Id = ClosestId
```

**Edit: Fixed up**

Got 200K+ rows to work with now.  I tried both ways, and the cross apply with an appropriate index (id/time + includes(..all columns...) worked just fine.  However, I ended up with the query I started, using a simpler (and existing) index on [id+time].  The more widely understandable query is why I settled on that one.  Maybe there still is a better way to do it, but I can't see it :D

```
-- subtree cost (crossapply) : .0808
-- subtree cost (id based)   : .0797

-- see above query for what i ended up with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

- changing the `inner join` to a `cross apply`.
- Move the `where log.stationid` to the subselect.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT log.*   -- id, 
FROM    dbo.fn_GenerateDateSteps(@st, @end, 30) AS d
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP 1 log.*
            FROM    lotsOfLogData AS log  -- contains data in 5 second intervals
            WHERE   -- search for dates in a certain range
                    utcTime between DATEADD(s, -10, d.dt) AND DATEADD(s, 5, d.dt)
                    AND log.stationid = 1000
            ORDER BY
                    -- get the 'closest'. this can change a little, but will always 
                    -- be based on a difference between the date
                    ABS(DATEDIFF(s, d.dt, UtcTime)) 
        ) log
```

Comment: The cross apply wants me to make an index on stationid/time that also includes *all* the other data in the table.  Without the index, it runs exactly the same as the naked query, so in this case the cross isn't going to work :)  I didn't even know about it though, so thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I did have a bug in that query ;)  I am *required* to put the stationId in the subquery because otherwise i'll match any stationId that is in the range.  After doing that, the proper index is used and everything is super fast (ish)

Comment: @AndrewBacker - Been away but thanks for keeping us informed.

Comment: Tried both, and for this dataset they came out almost identical (.0808 for subquery by id, .0797 for crossapply) Adding the correct index (id/time) works for the subquery by ID, and adding the one for crossapply (same, but INCLUDES() the extra columns) works as well.  I'll stick with the ID based one, though, since the index is easier to deal with (and more widely applicable, i think), as well as the query being more standard for maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Just some thoughts...wouldn't really call this an answer but it was too big for the comment box.

First of all, I would look at the execution plan for the query if you haven't done so already.

More esoteric: do you have the option to represent dates as primitive values (like an integer representing seconds/minutes since a well-defined time)? Even though I believe SQL Server stores dates as numeric values under the hood, operations on a primitive might be a little faster because it would eliminate the repeated calls to `DateAdd()` and `DateDiff()`.

[This (fairly old) article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/) gives examples of how SQL Server actually stores dates. Perhaps you could leave your dates as DATETIME but operate on them with basic math.

Regardless of data type, I would experiment with a clustered index on the date column, as it appears your searches could benefit from the physical ordering that a clustered index provides, especially if you are searching within tight ranges. Again, the execution plan would probably be enlightening.

I could also see a star schema being used to represent your data, with a date dimension that contained date generalizations. You could then search against the generalizations. Even if generalizations were not used, the actual number of dates would be reduced because all facts with the same date could point to the same record in the dimension, thus the date would only have to be evaluated once.

Lastly, what does the SQL performance tuning wizard (I believe it is in 2005, I know it is in 2008) suggest for your query? I wouldn't recommend blindly implementing its suggestions, but I often find good ideas in the things it recommends.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do much with the data format.  An external service receives the data and logs it there for us.  I've looked at the execution plan, but it is just huge =) I've got a clustered index on the station id, and a std. index on the date. I just don't have enough realistic data to test it yet, and with a small enough set it doesn't seem to matter if there is an index or not